# Unable to expand certain macros (GNU99 Compiler)

Tags: c, gcc

I'm trying to understand the C Pre-processor using the -E flag with gcc.

```
gcc -E -Wall simpleSocket.c
```

My source code is (keeping it simple):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>

int main(){
    int socketID = 0;
    int Socket_Protocol = 6;

    socketID = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,Socket_Protocol);
    printf("Socket created is %d",socketID);
    return 0;
}
```

The substituted code shows up:

```
int main(){                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    int socketID = 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    int Socket_Protocol = 6;                                                                                                                                                                                                                               

    socketID = socket(2,SOCK_STREAM,Socket_Protocol);                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    printf("Socket created is %d",socketID);                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    return 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
}
```

SOCK_STREAM does not get replaced although it is defined in *socket.h* library. I'm not able to figure out why that happened? I'm using the GNU99 compiler.

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Maybe it's an `enum` and not a `#define`.

Comment: @JS1: [Yup](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29933872/827263).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SOCK_STREAM` is not expanded because it's not a macro.

I grabbed a copy of your code and ran it through `gcc -E` on my system, and got similar results.  If you search the output for `SOCK_STREAM`, you'll find a definition similar to this (I've deleted some blank lines that were probably comments):

```
enum __socket_type
{
  SOCK_STREAM = 1,
  SOCK_DGRAM = 2,
  SOCK_RAW = 3,
  SOCK_RDM = 4,
  SOCK_SEQPACKET = 5,
  SOCK_DCCP = 6,
  SOCK_PACKET = 10,
  SOCK_CLOEXEC = 02000000,
  SOCK_NONBLOCK = 00004000
};
```

(An enumeration constant is a constant expression of type `int`.)

Comment: Ah that explains it. I was a little stumped going through the [source](http://unix.superglobalmegacorp.com/Net2/newsrc/sys/socket.h.html) of socket.h as it mentions SOCK_STREAM as #define.

Comment: @shark1608: There is no single source for socket.h. The version on your system and mine uses an `enum`; the version you linked to uses a `#define`. Both are probably valid. POSIX requires `SOCK_STREAM` to be a "symbolic constant".